# Does changing the output verbosity in Visual Studio 2010 affect build times?

Tags: c#, build, msbuild, console, solid-state-drive

I've recently installed an SSD into our systems to hopefully improve build times on our large projects.

Upon coming to test these drives I discovered that I could change the MSBuild output verbosity to normal to display a build timer in the output window.

My question is does this change in verbosity affect the build time compared to having it set to minimal?

Comment: Almost certainly, yes, but probably negligibly. Seems like a micro-opt compared to the power-up of SSD.

Comment: Only you can answer this question - for your particular project. Obviously, it depends on what type of projects you are doing and many other parameters.

Comment: Negligible, especially on SSD as spender mentioned. You'd start noticing more significant differences if you set the logging verbosity to diagnostic.